# Why is the CSS not loading?

Tags: support, design

Is there something wrong with Stack Exchange today? The formatting isn't right. Everything is just a long list and not easily readable:

[image: screenshot of page]

Here's what I get when trying to open the page in IE11:

[image]

Comment: Nope, nothing wrong here. Just clear your cache, and check your browser's console for any network issues. Could be a bad firewall/proxy setting.

Comment: Stop using IE.6 ! Hit `Crtl+F5`.

Comment: I am not using IE 6, I've tried in Chrome, Firefox, and IE11

Comment: possible related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After clearing cache and rebooting I found the problem.

My company's remote update server was causing the problem. It ended up not just messing up Stack Exchange, but several internal websites I have too. It's now fixed after allowing the updates and another reboot.

Comment: So you could actually reach all servers or were those blocked as well?

Comment: I was able to reach all servers, it just wasn't loading the CSS for Stack Exchange. Meta looked fine, and so did some of my internal sites. It seemed to cherry pick which ones to load the CSS and which not to. It was really weird.

Comment: Strange indeed. Thanks for reporting and posting the root cause.